# Regular expression in Java to match comma only if it occurs in the .css method signature

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular expression in Java which will match only if it is in the method signature of `.css` method.

For example

```
$('div').css( 'zIndex','10' );
```

In this case comma appears in the method signature of `.css`. Hence it should be matched.

Consider another example

```
$('div').css( 'zIndex' );
```

The example given below should not be matched as it has no comma in .css method.

I wrote a regex

```
\.css\(.+,.+\)
```

This works correctly in some cases only. 
For example `parseInt ( $('div').css('zIndex') , 10 );`
In this example regex should not have matched as there is no comma `.css` method, but my regex matches.
Please help how to do it in java?

Comment: Can you give some cases where it doesn't work like you expect? And by the way, do you only need to match or you want to do something with the match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
\.css\([^,)]+,[^)]+\)
```

In Java it can be translated to:

```
\\.css\\([^,)]+,[^)]+\\)
```

### [Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/ZRHlH5Wu9I)

Comment: This will work only if you have no coma in string nor a method called with more than one element like `$('div').css( test('a','b') );`

Comment: @Pierre-LouisLaffont: Yes I agree with you that above solutions works for simple non-nested cases only that are listed in OP's question. But I don't want to complicate the answer unless it is needed by the OP.

Comment: Thank you very much.It works perfectly. Sufficient for my case. But I want to know what the regex would be if the case is as mentioned by @Pierre-LouisLaffont.

Comment: May I know why you chose to un-accept this answer? Anyway to answer your question the regex would be: `\.css\([^,()]+,[^)]+\)` or you can see Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/dhelP7YQVl

Comment: I am extremely sorry. It happened by mistake. And thank you very much.

Comment: `$('div').css( test('a','b'),'none');`. For this test case the regex `\.css\([^,()]+,[^)]+\)` will not match. But from the requirement's view, regex should match the above test case, as it contains comma in the .css method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\.css\([^,)]+(,[^,)]+)+\)
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly for my case.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you should escape brackets

```
\.css[(][^,]+,[^,]+[)]
```

Comment: No need to do that at all.

Comment: @fge well, I' tried it from C# and it works. I think that should also work in Java as they both are using same regex rules

Comment: The problem is not from escaping but because there is a coma after the first closing bracket.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisLaffont possible, as I answered, the OP's question was not formatted and before the edit the brackets were not escaped at all. That was like `.css(.+,.+)` which is of course totally different than now